# "Code deprecation " in java

Tags: java, warnings

I use the date class to get the current hour with the function

```
Date date = new Date();
int t=date.getHours();
```

and eclipse keeps complaining about code deprecation. Everything works absolutely fine, but it keeps warning me about it, is there a reason I should change it? is there an alternative to getting current time?

Comment: Have you read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29)? *As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`.*

Comment: Nice to see people using StackOverflow, but I find it a bit disheartening when people post even trivial questions without even making as much of an effort as reading the javadoc or doing a very simple web-search.

Comment: I just have no idea what deprecated in programming context means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of a library are marked *deprecated* when an issue is found with them but the designers decide that an improvement on the existing part could break many existing programs that already rely on the old behavior.

So, they keep the existing part, at least for some time (to maintain the ability of existing sources to compile until they are updated), while usually offering an alternative instead.

Now, regarding time in Java, most people recommend [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you! Finally an answer that answers to my questions, and not just mentions it...!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [java.util.Date API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29)

[getHours()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29) is a deprecated method

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).

Comment: I suppose the OP is referring to java.util.Date, not java.sql.Date

Comment: @assylias oh yeah, edited it , BTW java.sql.Date's getHours() is deprecated as well .:)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you should change it is that `java.util.Date` is broken in many subtle ways. Your code may work in certain situations and fail in others (for example, when you run it on a computer with a different time zone, when a cracker attacks your application, when someone messed with serialized `Date` objects, ...)

In 2013, you shouldn't use `java.util.Date` anymore. Use `Calendar`, if you must, or the much better [joda-time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: And from September 2013, switch to Java 8 and enjoy the new Joda-like Date API ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Date#getHours` is deprecated:

> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).

Answer (score 0):

The reason to change is that deprecated code is "marked" to be removed in future release, so you should not use deprecated method in your code if you plan to maintain it over time.
As for what to do to get the hour, from Date Javadoc:

```
As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getHours` is deprecated as of JDK version 1.1. You should use `java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` instead:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int t = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081123050802AAL0gAm

Basically, you can still use the method. But it may not be supported for the next few versions of java.

BTW, you can get around the problem by using Calendar class.